# H. P. Lovecraft & his texts

Tags: books, h-p-lovecraft

Does anyone know why H. P. Lovecraft always (or very often) uses the &-sign instead of "and" in his texts?

Comment: Why does there need to be a reason?  It's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: Could simply have been to reduce character count and type setters did it.

Comment: The dread ratiocination behind use of the & is spoken of only in whispers, among those who have dared to glimpse the unhallowed pages of the fabled *Necronomicon* and wandered forbidden cyclopean ruins. The reasoning is too terrifying to recount here, among pitiful mortal humans who are as less than termites beside the vast and incomprehensible horrors which rule the cosmos.

Comment: This is a question about English grammar. It has nothing to do with Sci-Fi/Fantasy.

Comment: This is a question about English grammar. It has nothing to do with Sci-Fi/Fantasy.

Comment: @Deion It *might* be relevant if someone could show that Lovecraft's usage of the ampersand has meaning. Perhaps his correspondence indicates he found its twisting shape fitting his thoughts and ideas. 
However, I doubt that's the case. :)

Comment: This question is out of scope here, and from my understanding, at all of the English language stacks as well.

Answer (score 3):

Lovecraft often used the [epistolary style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistolary_novel) for his stories. I've just searched through a couple of Lovecraft collections, and the ["&"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ampersand) symbol shows up most often in in-universe notes, letters and lists - items written in a hurry or for personal use. It's also frequently used in railroad company names ([such as the B & M Railroad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_and_Maine_Corporation)); rail travel was common in HPL's day.

Comment: He had a strong aesthetic attraction to the 18th century, in part because the family library was filled with books from that period which he grew up reading. See [this article](http://electricliterature.com/field-notes-from-a-fulbright-scholar-lovecrafts-quebec/) which quotes a letter where he said "I think I am probably the only living person to whom the ancient 18th century idiom is actually a prose & poetic mother-tongue", and the article notes that "he insists on archaic spelling (scientifick, phantasy, antient)", something I've noticed in his letters too. Was "&" more common in 18th c.?